# ignore styles coming from database

Tags: css

I am displaying some database contents on my website, which have been saved into the database using a text editor with its own styles. However, I would need the text to be displayed with the css defined style. I already marked all css styles as important, but in some cases it still shows the styles as defined within the text.

Here is my css:

```
    p.new { 
    text-align:justify !important;
    font-size:15px !important; 
    font-weight:bold !important; 
    font-family:CrimsonRoman, Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif !important;
    position: relative !important; margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px !important; 
    color: rgb(255, 226, 163) !important; 
    letter-spacing:2px !important; 
    }
```

and here is how I display the text:

```
    <p class="new">
<?php 

       if(isset($page_content) and $page_content->num_rows()>0)
   { 
   foreach($page_content->result() as $page)
     {
     $value = $default_lang . "_content";                           
     echo $page->$value;
     }
   }
?>
</p>
```

The $page->$value; has its own style which is defined by the db contents, here a sample of the HTML code:

```
<p class="new">
<p><strong style="border: 0px #240804; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align:       baseline; color: #666666; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;">Para solicitar informaci&oacute;n sobre tarifas o posibles actividades o eventos, no dude en localizarnos a trav&eacute;s de este formulario o usando el apartado &ldquo;contacto&rdquo; , donde tienen todos nuestros datos.</strong></p>
<p style="border: 0px #240804; margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; color: #666666; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"><strong style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px #240804; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: baseline;">C&oacute;mo hacer una reserva&nbsp; :</strong></p>
<p><strong style="border: 0px #240804; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; color: #666666; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"></strong></p>
<ol style="border: 0px #240804; margin: 0px 0px 15px 32px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style-position: initial; list-style-image: initial; color: #666666; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;">
<li style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px #240804; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">Por favor complete sus datos y env&iacute;enos este formulario.</li>
<li style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px #240804; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">Le enviaremos un documento para que complete su reserva.</li>
<li style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px #240804; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">Le enviaremos la confirmaci&oacute;n de su reserva</li>
</ol>    
</p>
```

Any idea? I tried so many things and I am running out of ideas.... Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What do you mean by "the `$page->$value;` has its own style"?

Comment: Do you have an example of the HTML source with the content of <p class="new">?

Comment: Since that page content can potentially be anything, you pretty much have to overwrite every possible style with a more specific rule, which is _extremely_ difficult at the moment.

Comment: do you have style tags inside the value ?

Comment: @Donut $page->$value; displays the database contents, which contain the text with style tags. it might for example contain something like <font color="red">TEXT OF THE DATABASE</font>. What I am trying is that the <font> tag is ignored in order to apply the p class="new" defined styles.

Comment: Here is a sample of the HTML:

Comment: <p class="new">
<p><strong style="border: 0px #240804; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; color: #666666; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;"></strong></p>
<ol style="border: 0px #240804; margin: 0px 0px 15px 32px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style-position: initial; list-style-image: initial; color: #666666; font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;">
</ol>   
</p>

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I don't know what is the next element is but if you want to apply the style to all the children of p.new than you should do following.

```
p.new * { 
    text-align:justify !important;
    font-size:15px !important; 
    font-weight:bold !important; 
    font-family:CrimsonRoman, Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif !important;
    position: relative !important; margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px !important; 
    color: rgb(255, 226, 163) !important; 
    letter-spacing:2px !important; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this didnt do it. I have added a html sample to the original question...

Comment: ok so p.new wont work you have to change the top p tag to div tag.   here is a js fiddle link        http://jsfiddle.net/jspatel/3YbtL/